# Making model associations for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, associations, model-associations

I'm having some trouble on how to make my associations for my rails website, this is my first project with rails so please bear with me. If you don't understand something, please let me know.

My website will be a weekly'pickem nfl website where users can enter multiple pools and admins will be able to create pools so regular users can enter and play.

If you don't know what a nfl weekly pickem is read this if you do, skip this paragraph. An NFL Weekly Pickem basically is a game where you pick which nfl teams you think will win each week. On week one lets say there are 16 games, you choose one team per game. You get one point for each game you guessed right and at the end of the week, the user that guesses the most wins the week. This goes on for all the season and  normally at the end of the season, the top 10 users with the most guesses get a prize...

Now that I cleared that out let me get to my point

Currently my classes and associations are:

User - usual info, name, email, etc..

```
Model: User
has_many :groups
has_many :pools, through: :groups
```

Pool - with only the pool name

```
Model: Pool
has_many :groups
has_many :users, through: :groups
```

Groups - model that joins pools and users

```
Model: Group
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :pool
```

Match - home team, visit team, points, etc..

Team - I store team name and thinking about storing their logo

As you can see, I already have the association between User and Pool so that one user can be in multiple pools and one pool can have multiple users.

My questions are:

How can I make it so that one pool can have many matches different from the other pools? This is so that in the future I can make pools for nba others for nfl, mlb, etc..

How can I make it so that one user can pick a team that thinks will win? Remember, this user can be in multiple pools, therefore one pick only applies to a specific pool.

I was thinking of making something like this although it is not working :(

```
picks
Model:Pick
belongs_to:user
belongs_to:match
belongs_to:pool
date:datetime
```

Comment: I think you should add a Round model as well, so that you can keep track easily of each weeks scores. Your Pick model also looks fine, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Or maybe you need to relate it through Group. I'll post an answer.

Comment: I would start with a baseline of the simplest, most critical feature of your app, without caring much about the rest of the models/associations until they are needed. In this case, the most important feature seems to be that `Users` can make many `Picks`. Since this is a many-to-many relationship, you can create a bridge table like `UserPicks` that references `User` and `Pick`...then build your associations from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should draw a diagram for this relationship, that makes it a lot easier, as this is quite complex.

If your User and Pool are related through Group, your Pick model could use that one:

```
Model:Pick
belongs_to :match
belongs_to :group
belongs_to :round
date:datetime
```

You could do `Pick.group.user` to get the user, or `Pick.group.pool` to get the pool

And like I suggested, I added a model round as well, which could keep track of each week's rounds.

Comment: ok so this is what im looking for...

im not liking the name of the Group model.. im thinking of just naming it UserScore since this table is gonna be used to add users to pools and viceversa but also add a score for each user so you know how many points one user has on each pool he is on...
and the round model is a great idea thanks

Comment: now in the case of picking a team for a match... shouldnt there be attribute picked_team on the Pick model? That way i can go user.user_scores.pick.picked_team? btw im not liking user_scores now lol i dont know what to name that model